# Unable to infer base url - Spring 4.2, Spring Security 4.2, Swagger 2.8.0

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, swagger

1. When I access my api: http://xx/api/v1/reference, click on the
   Swagger, I get: [Unable to infer base url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEtz8.png) **How do I fix this?**
   In my class I have:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @Order(1)
   public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token-header-name}")
   private String principalRequestHeader;

   @Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token}")
   private String principalRequestValue;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       APIKeyAuthFilter filter = new APIKeyAuthFilter(principalRequestHeader);
       filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

           @Override
           public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
               String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
               if (!principalRequestValue.equals(principal))
               {
                   throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
               }
               authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
               return authentication;
           }
       });
       httpSecurity.           
          antMatcher("/api/**").
           csrf().disable().
           sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
           and().

           addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

   }
   ```

   }

I know several questions like this have been posted:
None answer my question. Apparently this is fixed in Springfox 2.8.1-SNAPSHOT. Can anyone provide me a solution that works in Springfox 2.8.0?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried whitelisting the following ?

```
"/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger.json", "/webjars/**"
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work for me. Using Swagger- 2.9.2, Spring 2.1.3.RELEASE, Spring security 5.1.4.RELEASE